# When remodeling a hallway with new walls and ceiling, should walls be done first or ceiling?

Tags: walls

Should walls be done first or ceiling? I'm doing in plywood with FRP covering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do the ceiling first but have a lift. 
If doing all by hand you could make life easier by doing 1 wall with enough gap to slip the ceiling panel over the wall then it will stay on that ledge while you hold it up  and secure.  This is how I did most jobs prior to getting my first lift.

Comment: You can also create the "ledge" by screwing scraps (e.g., 2x4 or whatever you have around) in appropriate places. Use screws so the "ledge" is easy to remove once the ceiling is up.

Comment: Sure that would work I have also made a T with a stud and a short pice of 2x  but I don’t waste time with scraps, well and I am a big guy I can do sheetrock in 8’ without stilts but use them for taller ceilings.

Comment: I agree with Ed.... have always used the one wall method.... didn't do enough to buy a lift...+

Comment: Thanks all. I think that "ledge" method sounds good. Will give that a try, Doing this alone so hoping can do.